# Need some help to write a python script

Tags: python

I need help writing a Python script that will parse this particular GO annotation file, and output only the lines that describe a biological processes (P).  Sample output will look like as shown in the image.
This what I have so far..

`import sys
              import re
              file_object = open(sys.argv[[1]])
                 for some_line in file_object:
                 some_line = some_line.strip('\n')
                    list = some_line.split("\t")
                         if re.search('>', some_line):
                            sys.stdout.write(list[1]+ "\t")`

I want to format this file http://downloads.yeastgenome.org/curation/literature/go_slim_mapping.tab so that output only the lines that describe a biological processes (P).

Comment: "I need help" <- fair enough, what is the question?

Comment: The sample input and output would help

Comment: Image?  Do I need glasses?

Comment: @varesa Unless they can tell us what specific problem they're having with this code, we can't really help anyway. The question so far sounds like he's asking us to finish the script for them.

Comment: What a title , _Please help me_

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't post the image because my reputation is less than 10

Comment: @Arman: Was that helpful?  I'll admit I didn't word *my* comment very well, but I don't even see a purpose in yours.

Comment: @zondo , I mention him don't choose title same as this for his questions as you mentioned not put image like this , any problem?

Comment: I don't really get the problem. You need to filter only the lines that have 4th column as "P"?

Comment: Why python? Sounds like a job for grep... No? Based on the wording of the question.

Comment: I apologise for the delay. My input is the link and output should only have P in the 4th column

Comment: @Arman: They way it was worded, it seemed like you were making fun of him.  You didn't give him any information on what was wrong with it, or what he could do to improve it.

Comment: I want to write a python script even though I can do this on grep. I'm learning how to write python script

Comment: @zondo as you did in your comment , but sure I didn't make any fun here

Comment: @Arman: In my comment I gave all necessary information: there is no image.  In yours, you just said "What a title".  Is that supposed to be helpful to him?  How will that help him improve his future titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex just looks at the 4th value (In the format Value-Spaces-Value-Spaces-Value-Spaces...), and checks if it's a 'P' with withespace after. If it matches then it prints the line

```
import sys
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\S+\s+){2,3}P\s.*')
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #Consider striping the line if it's necessary
        if regex.search(line):
            print(line)
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use this script: Traceback (most recent call last): File "parseG0", line 5, in <module>
    with open(sys.argv[[1]]) as file:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: I'm sorry, in line `with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:` there was double brackets, I corrected it, should work now

Comment: Note: some input rows (ie lines 23, 26 of the sample) do not have a value in the second column. Your regex will treat `\t\t` as a single run of spaces and reject these lines (which should be included). Maybe you should use `\s` instead of `\s+`?

Answer (score 0):

This does the same as @MrE's answer but without using `re`.

The file is tab-delimited, so we can do:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split('\t', 4)
        if len(parts) >= 4 and parts[3] == 'P':
            print(line, end='')
```